# Footer Should be at bottom of page/content

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to figure out how to make the footer stick to bottom. If Content is less than Size footer should be at bottom & if content is larger than window size, footer should be at end of content.I know there are tons of material on Internet that how to stick you footer to bottom. Below Code working fine when Content large:

HERE IS MY HTML:

```
<html>
 <body ng-cloak> 
   <notifications-bar class="notifications"></notifications-bar> 
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
     <ng-include src="'app/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
     <div ng-view></div>
     <ng-include src="'app/layout/footer.html'"></ng-include> 
   </div> 
  <spinner></spinner> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

HERE IS CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html {  position: relative;   min-height:100%;
}

html, body {    margin:0px;    padding:0px;
}   

.footer_body {
  background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  margin:0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To keep your footer fixed at bottom, position:fixed; bottom:0;

Answer (score 1):

Your footer position should be `absolute` not `relative` and the `top`-styling should be removed. Perhaps check out [bootstraps sticky footer source code](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). It doesn't matter whether you're using bootstrap or not, the styling for the sticky footer is the same regardless.

Here's the essential parts of it:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;  /* height of footer */
}
.footer_body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;  /* height of footer */
    background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body ng-cloak> 
    <notifications-bar class="notifications"></notifications-bar> 
    
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
        <div ng-view></div>   
    </div> 
    
    <footer class="footer_body">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/footer.html'"></ng-include> 
    </footer>
    <spinner></spinner>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.!! Please help me one more time.

Comment: If you found this answers your question, please consider marking it as answered. If you have a different question, feel free to create a new question with it and I'll see if I can help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky` these days

Demo Pen https://codepen.io/D-Heap/pen/RjwEEr

That is if you don't need much backward compatibility (especially for IE).
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky.